Angular 17 select error core.mjs:6531 ERROR Error: NG05105: Unexpected synthetic listener @transformPanel.done found
I have a select that controls a list that just doesn't seem to be working. The error I get in the console is
core.mjs:6531 ERROR Error: NG05105: Unexpected synthetic listener @transformPanel.done found. Please make sure that:

Either BrowserAnimationsModule or NoopAnimationsModule are imported in your application.

Typescript:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'; 
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

export interface legend {
  name: string;
  image: string;
  tooltip: string;
}
export interface maplist {
  name: string;
  legends: Array<legend>
}



@Component({
  selector: 'app-legend',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatListModule, MatIconModule, MatDividerModule, DatePipe,
    MatSelectModule, MatTooltipModule, MatFormFieldModule, FormsModule, 
  ],
  providers: [
    provideAnimations()
  ],
  templateUrl: './legend.component.html',
  styleUrl: './legend.component.css',
})
export class LegendComponent {
  selectedValue: Array<legend> = [];

  maplistdata: maplist[] = [
    {
      name: "Echocondria",
      legends: [
        {
          name: "House",
          image: "",
          tooltip: "Living quarters for the residents."
        },
        {
          name: "Shop",
          image: "",
          tooltip: "Places to buy and sell goods."
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Echocondria Sewers",
      legends: [
        {
          name: "House",
          image: "",
          tooltip: "Living quarters for the residents."
        },
        {
          name: "Shop",
          image: "",
          tooltip: "Places to buy and sell goods."
        },
      ]
    },
  ]
}

HTML:
  <mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
  <mat-select 
    color="primary"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="legendselect"
  >
    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
    @for (legend of maplistdata; track legend) {
        <mat-option [value]="legend.legends">{{legend.name}}</mat-option>
    }
   </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>

  @for (legenditem of selectedValue; track legenditem) {
  <mat-list-item>
  <mat-icon matListItemIcon>folder</mat-icon>
  <div matListItemTitle [matTooltip]="legenditem.tooltip"><img class="legendIcon" [src]="legenditem.image"/> {{ legenditem.name }}</div>
   <div matListItemLine>{{legenditem.tooltip}}</div>
</mat-list-item>
  }


I've tried importing the modules in question but still get the same error or an error that the module is already included.

The provider provideAnimations() belongs are the root of your application. Either in the config of boostrapApplication, or if you're relying on a AppModule, you should import BrowserAnimationModule.
